# Determining language of twitter posts

Tags: twitter

What is the best way to determine the language of twitter posts.

There is the language parameter that comes with the streaming API but it doesn't really seem to be very accurate. Even many Japanese posts are labelled as English.

What have others done to sort out the langauges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had very good results with this PHP package: 
http://pear.php.net/package/Text_LanguageDetect/

It is fast and open source. We use it to select English only posts for a site we run at http://2012twit.com.

Comment: That makes sense and looks like a good library. It doesn't appear to be able to pull Japanese (a nice to have and I can write a php workaround for that)

Answer (score 1):

google have language detection within their Translate API if using <del>evil</del> external services is a go-er?

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/reference.html#detectResult

Comment: I have nothing against an external API but the time delay in making a request out is a bit troublesome but will give it a shot.